# Food Themed Cryptic Clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

Continuing a series a started a few days ago, here are some more cryptic-crossword-style clues. This time, the theme is food and drink.

> Heard complaint about bottle (4)
>
> Animal has morning in pound (4)
>
> Syrup for monkey, around one thousand and fifty (5)
>
> Initially, Robert is chopping eggs for grain (4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: got the first one thanks to @jhabbott and the last thanks to @f''

Heard complaint about bottle (4)

> Wine - sounds like *whine*.

Animal has morning in pound (4)

> L**am**b - which is *A.M.* in *lb* (short for pound).

Syrup for monkey, around one thousand and fifty (5)

> **M**ap**l**e - which is *ape* around *ML* (Roman number for 1050).

Initially, Robert is chopping eggs for grain (4)

> <s>**B**ran - the first intial of *Bob* (short for Robert) then a chopping of *free-**ran**ge eggs*</s>.
>  Rice - the intial letters of ***R**obert **i**s **c**hopping   **e**ggs*.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of wine (whine) for the first one, was getting nowhere with the others though, good job.

Comment: Hey well done, couldn't get anywhere with that! Added to answer, thanks.

Comment: @f'' That's got to be it. Thought mine was a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @PaulEvans Bran is not correct for the fourth one. F" has got it. Change and then I will accept, because the others are all correct.

Comment: @PaulEvans you got it now!